# Why do we use css files for each APP in Django?

Tags: css, django

I'm following a Django course on Udemy where the instructor used specific `css` files for each app he created, my question is very simple: Why do need to create `css` files for each app? i'm asking this because those specific `css` files for that particular can affect other styles of the website.

Like why can't we just create global `css` files for the whole website and thats it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nearly all frameworks, apps are designed to be stand alone elements that are inserted into a web page. They are often meant to be replaceable within the page with a different app as well as transferable, in that the can be used for other web pages. Having a CSS file for each app ensures that the app itself is stable across multiple use cases. Many frameworks also employ a css stylesheets for the `index.html` file, or the base webpage that contains the component apps.

Comment: Thank you, this is simple enough, so it's not a must its just a convention or lets say best practice.

Comment: Yes, "best practices" is probably the best way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Django does not limit you to having a per app css file.  That is a coding convention that was used by the instructor, and it is likely a good idea, as was pointed out by J__carlson.  You can call your css file from any other app using the same template code.

For instance, this line may refer to the `main.css` file for app1, but this line can be inserted into an html file in app2 as well.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app1/css/main.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```

While this seems to satisfy the principle of only writing code once, the issue you will have is that any app that refers to code outside itself will not be portable, and you will have to modify it on a project by project basis if you try to reuse the code elsewhere.